# Chaining .then() calls in ES6 promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I thought it was supposed to be possible to chain the .then() method when using ES6 Promises. In other words I thought that when a promise is resolved the value passed to the resolve function should be passed to any chained *then* handlers. If this is so how come *value* comes back undefined in the chained *then* handler below?

```
function createPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(true);
  });
}

createPromise()
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // expected: true, actual: true
  })
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // expected: true, actual: undefined
  });
```

Comment: You're not returning anything for the chained `.then()` to use as the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each `then()` can return a value that will be used as the resolved value for the next `then()` call. In your first `then()`, you don't return anything, hence `value` being undefined in the next callback. Return `value` in the first one to make it available in the second.

```js
function createPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(true);
  });
}

createPromise()
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // expected: true, actual: true
    return value;
  })
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // expected: true, actual: true
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return it inside a promise to pass it along. Or create a new promise that resolves with it.

```
createPromise()
.then((value) => {
    return value;
})
.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Or

```
createPromise()
.then((value) => {
    return new Promise.resolve(value);
})
.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.then` always returns a Promise that resolves to the value returned in the function callback. Since you return nothing in the first call to `.then`, `undefined` becomes the resolved value of the Promise returned.

In other words, if you want to resolve `true` in the second call to `.then`, you'll have to return it in the first, like so,

```
createPromise() // returns a Promise
  .then(function (value) {
    console.log(value); // => true
    return value; // now this will return a Promise that resolves the value `true`
  }).then(function (value) {
    console.log(value) // => true
  });
```

You can refer to [MDN's documentation on method chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining) for ES2015 promises if you need further information.