# About chaining es6 Promises, then() and value consumption

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

This is tightly coupled to [Chaining .then() calls in ES6 promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556251/chaining-then-calls-in-es6-promises) ...

I tried this with some functions that make up a chain of promises, so basically:

```
var PromiseGeneratingMethod = function(){
  return p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    resolve(1)
  });
}

var inBetweenMethod = function(){
  return PromiseGeneratingMethod()
    .then((resolved) => {
    if(resolved){
      console.log('resolved in between');
      //return resolved
        /* this changes output to
        resolved in between
        resolved at last*/
    }else{
      console.log('something went terribly wrong in betweeen', resolved);
    }
  });
}

inBetweenMethod().then((resolved) =>{
  if(resolved){
    console.log('resolved at last')
  }else{
    console.log('something went terribly wrong', resolved);
  }
})

/* ouput: 
resolved in between
something went terribly wrong undefined*/
```

I don't understand why it is like that. doesn't have a Promise just ONE associated return value? why can I change that value in every then? It seems irrational to me. A Promise Object can only have one return value and I thought every then handler will receive the same parameter after the Promise gets resolved?

This way, having two Methods which call then() on the same Promise, the latter one (in asynchronous environments you never know what that is...) will ALWAYS get an empty result, except if EVERY then returns the desired value

If I got it right, the only good thing is that you can build a then().then().then() chain to make it almost synchronous (by returning arbitrary values in every then()) but you still could achieve the same with nested Promises, right?

Can someone help me understand why es6 Promises work that way and if there are more caveats to using those?

Comment: Your `PromiseGeneratingMethod` assigns to the [implicitly global `p` variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) - by accident?

Comment: Just to be clear, `resolved` in your `inBetweenMethod` is `1`.

Comment: You'd probably benefit from reading one of the many tutorials on how Promises work that's already out there instead of hoping that somebody types in a new treatise here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> doesn't have a promise just ONE associated return value?

Yes.

> why can I change that value in every then?

Because every `.then()` call does return a *new* promise.

> having two methods which call then() on the same Promise

That's not what you're doing. Your `then` callbacks are installed on *different* promises, that's why they get different values.

You *could* do

```
function inBetweenMethod() {
  var promise = PromiseGeneratingMethod();
  promise.then(resolved => { … }); // return value is ignored
  return promise;
}
```

but you should really avoid that. You already noticed that you can get the expected behaviour with

```
function inBetweenMethod() {
  var promise = PromiseGeneratingMethod();
  var newPromise = promise.then(value => {
     …
     return value;
  });
  return newPromise;
}
```

where the `newPromise` is resolved with the value that is returned by the callback - possibly the same value that `promise` fulfilled with.

Answer (score 2):

you are using `.then()` handler twice, do the following:

```
var PromiseGeneratingMethod = function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    if (myCondition) resolve(1)
    if (!myCondition) reject("failed")
  });
}

var inBetweenMethod = function(){
  return PromiseGeneratingMethod()
}

inBetweenMethod().then((resolved) =>{
  console.log(resolved)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```